# calling virtual function through pointer to const base class

Tags: c++

In the below program, the function 'f' in the base class A is hidden for the objects of derived class B. But when I call function f through const A *d which is pointing object of B, function f from the base class is getting invoked. If I remove const specifier for the pointer (i.e. A *d) function 'f' from derived class is called. My query  how the constness is making a difference here ? Thanks for any help.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void f(int n) { std::cout << "A::f\n"; }
    virtual ~A() { }

    void f(int n) const { std::cout << "A::f const\n"; }
};

class B
    : public A
{
public:
    void f(int n) { std::cout << "B::f\n"; }

    void f(int n) const { std::cout << "B::f const\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    const A a;
    B b;
    A &c = b;
    const A *d = &b;

    c.f(1);
    d->f(1);


    return 0;
}
```

Output (with const A *d):
B::f
A::f const

Output (with A* d)
B::f
B::f

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of the function to be called is determined on call site based on the *static* type of the pointer. The correct overrider of this signature is then chosen at runtime.

In other words, if you have this:

```
const A *d;
d->f(1);
```

then the `f` is searched for in `const A`. So it finds the non-virtual `void f(int) const`.

However, if you have this:

```
A *e;
e->f(1);
```

then the `f` is searched for in non-const `A`. So it finds `virtual void f(int)`, which is then (at runtime) delegated to the final overrider `void B::f(int)`.

**EDIT**

This follows from the rules on member function selection. When accessing through a `const` path (pointer or reference), only `const` member functions are applicable. When accessing through a non-const path, non-const functions are considered. Only if there is none is the pointer (or reference) implicitly converted to a pointer (or-reference) to `const` and then the `const` member functions are considered.